# Which sentence is better to use?

Tags: word-usage

Which one of the following is correct?

> Placed his work of art on the museum wall last week

or

> Placed last week his work of art on the museum wall

Comment: Neither option is actually a sentence - both are just verb phrases.

Answer (score 2):

In English, one of the few almost-categorical restrictions on placement of adverbials ("last week", "on the museum wall") is that they almost *never* come between a verb ("placed") and its direct object ("his work of art"). So only your first version is OK.

(But note that it's not a complete sentence yet: it still needs a subject!)

Comment: @Kai *Museum wall* is a correct use of an attributive noun (noun-as-adjective).

Comment: That's correct; and as such, the word "placed" almost definitely shouldn't be capitalized in this sentence. ("X subject placed his work of art on the _museum_ wall...".)